# glassfish 3.1 jdni lookup on EJB3

Tags: jndi

I have the following Interfaces **MyLocalBean, MyRemoteBean** and the stateless **MyBean** *implements* MyLocalBean, MyRemoteBean
Which of the following i don't need to get a simple java application to test this ...

**ejb-jar.xml, glassfish-ejb-jar.xml, gf-client.jar**

Here's ejb-jar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:ejb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
   <enterprise-beans>
      <session>
         <ejb-name>MyEJB</ejb-name>
         <home>test.ejb.MyLocalBean</home>
         <remote>test.ejb.MyRemoteBean</remote>
         <ejb-class>test.ejb.MyBean </ejb-class>
         <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
         <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
      </session>
   </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

what's missing here? would i be able to lookup using MyEJB?

and here's my lookup code

```
InitialContext ic;
ic = new InitialContext();
MyRemoteBean remoteBean = 
        (MyRemoteBean ) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/MyEJB");
```

[EDIT]

I've update the ejb-jar.xml as follows

```
<enterprise-beans>
    <session>
        <ejb-name>MyEJB</ejb-name>
        <ejb-class>test.ejb.MyBean</ejb-class>
        <ejb-local-ref>
            <ejb-ref-name>MyEJB</ejb-ref-name>
            <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
            <local>test.ejb.MyLocalBean</local>
            <ejb-link>MyEJBClient.jar#MyEJB</ejb-link>
        </ejb-local-ref>
    </session>
</enterprise-beans>
```

I get an error ...

> cannot Deploy MyBeanEAR
>   Deployment Error for module:
>   MyBeanEAR: Error occurred
>   during deployment: Exception while
>   deploying the app [MyBeanEAR] :
>   Error: Unresolved :
>   MyEJBClient.jar#MyEJB.
>   Please see server.log for more
>   details.

[\EDIT]

[EDIT]

Hi bkail, let me brake down the problem using the correct names.. Initially, this is what my eclipse-sts IDE created by default

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:ejb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>BatchOverrideEJB</display-name>
  <ejb-client-jar>BatchOverrideEJBClient.jar</ejb-client-jar>
</ejb-jar>
```

and this is how i tried accessing the EJB

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost","localhost");
p.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort","3700");
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(p);

ic = new InitialContext(p);

BatchOverrideManagerRemote batchOverrideRemote = 
    (BatchOverrideManagerRemote) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/BatchOverrideEJB");
```

running this i got the following error

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:645)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:325)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at za.co.sanlam.batchovveride.test.BatchOverrideTester.main(BatchOverrideTester.java:33)
```

I thought this error meant that my EJB its not bound to the context, so i modified the ejb-jar.xml as follows

```
<ejb-jar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:ejb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
    <enterprise-beans>
        <session>
            <ejb-name>BatchOverrideEJB</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.test.ejb.BatchOverrideManagerBean</ejb-class>
            <ejb-local-ref>
                <ejb-ref-name>BatchOverrideEJB</ejb-ref-name>
                <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
                <local>com.test.batchoverridemanager.ejb.BatchOverrideManagerLocal</local>
                <ejb-link>BatchOverrideEJB</ejb-link>
            </ejb-local-ref>
        </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar
```

but now i get javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: Use rebind to override
[/EDIT]

Answer (score 1):

Try `<ejb-link>MyEJB</ejb-link>`.  That said, `test.ejb.MyLocalEJB` doesn't sound like a home interface that extends EJBHome, so perhaps you meant to use `<business-remote>` rather than `<remote>` and `<home>`?  If you're using a container that supports EJB 3.1, you'll probably find it easier to just use annotations:

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean implements MyLocal { ... }
@Local
public interface MyLocal { ... }
@Remote
public interface MyRemote { ... }
```

As an aside `MyLocalBean` and `MyRemoteBean` are unusual names for business interfaces.  Typically, the `Bean` suffix is reserved for the EJB class itself.

**Edit #2:**

For the second edit, see this link:

http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#nonJavaEEwebcontainerRemoteEJB

Comment: Hi bkail, i've edited the question because i can't seem to post a reply to my own question. Please consider the 2nd [EDIT] part .. thanks